# Как вставить переменную $_SESSION['username']==dbusername

Tags: php

```
<?php

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db_name = "";
$tbl_name = "";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");

}
else{  
echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}

?>
```

Как в этот код вставить переменную `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы уже по-моему вставили, вот в этом кусочке кода:

```
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
```

Попробуйте вывести полностью $_SESSION, там уже должна быть информация, сделать это можно так:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

ну или если версия пхп старая, то можно и по старинке, в самом верху скрипта `session_start();` а потом уже присваивайте переменные по типу такого

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

PS у вас там кстате sql injection образовалось (:

Comment: ))

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разгребем, что вы тут написали, хотябы самые основы.

```
    <?php

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db_name = "";
$tbl_name = "";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
//во первых предотвращаем sqlinjection.
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
//так как вы не собираетесь использовать данные полученные из запроса, то нам не кчему лишние телодвижения.
/*
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {*/ 
//заменяем на:
if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'")){
//присваиваем значения $_SESSION, в принципе это делается в следующих строках, но если вам не терпится заюзать суперглобальный массив меняем их на:
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
//  session_register("username");
//  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");

}
else{  
echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}

?>
```

P.S. Влад, если вы считаете, что получили ответ на свой вопрос, нажмите галочку, возле правильного ответа, чтобы показать другим пользователям, что на вопрос уже ответили. Я это говорю, про все ваши вопросы.

Comment: $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];

а фильтрация параметров сессии ?, прямо вот так в сессию нефильтрофф отдаешь?

Answer (score 1):

`sessin_registr()` не сработает, пока в начале файла не вызовите `session_start();`

```
<?php
  @session_start();
  ............
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
?>
```

Comment: В мане написано что session_register() сам вызывает session_start если его нет

Comment: незнаю, у меня без session_start() не работает чета...